# C++ error variable declared void when passing array into function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to refresh myself in C++ before my college starts again and I ran into some problems. I'm using a bubblesort function given by my professor and I'm struggling to run it in my int main. The function parameters is `bubblesort(int *a, int length)`, so I used `bubblesort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) )`.
The compiler shows an error ' a ' is declared void. I tried searching up for an answer if I made a mistake but I couldn't catch my error. If you understand why I am getting this error can you please explain in detail what I'm missing or doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubblesort(int *a, int length)
{  
    int i, temp, finished = 0; 
   while(!finished)
   {  
       finished = 1;
      for( i = 0; i< length-1; i++)
      {  
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]) 
         {  
            temp = a[i]; 
            a[i] = a[i+1]; 
            a[i+1] = temp;
            finished = 0; 
         } 
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   int a[] = {5,1,7,9,4,3};
   for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);i++){ cout << a[i]; }
   cout << endl;
   void bubblesort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
   for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);i++){ cout << a[i]; }
}
```

Comment: Read a book about [programming in C++](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), and invoke it with all warnings and debug info, so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Except for `cout`, your code is in C, not in genuine C++

Answer (score 3):

You don't need return type in function call.

Remove `void` from the line

```
void bubblesort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
```

and make it

```
bubblesort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
```

Comment: well wow, i feel embarrassed how could I not notice something so obvious

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify the return type of a function when making a function call, so you need:

```
bubblesort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));  // no void at the beginning
```

However, you have a fixed-size array, so the call could also simply be:

```
bubblesort(a, std::size(a));
```

---

Also, this loop:

```
for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);i++){ cout << a[i]; }
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
for (int elem : a)
  cout << elem;
```

Comment: The array isn't static. `std::size(a)` works because `a` is the name of the array. When an array is passed to a function, the function sees a pointer and not an array, so in that context, `std::size` won't work.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm sorry, I don't understand. The array `a` *is* static. It decays to a pointer when passed to the function, but at the call site you can use `size` to get the length, and that's the information needed by the function. I'm not suggesting that `size` will work in the called function.

Comment: The array has automatic storage duration. For it to be static it would have to be defined in global scope, in namespace scope, or with the keyword `static`. In all those cases, `std::size(a)` would also work, again because the name is the name of an array and not the name of a pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Aah, I see what you mean. I was misusing `static`. Changed it to `fixed-size`. Is it correct now?

Comment: Better, but I prefer the wording that I used: it's the name of an array (and not the name of a pointer). By definition, and array has a fixed size. But I'm a bit of a pedant here: when you pass an array into a function the function sees a pointer; nothing more. Yes, that pointer might point to the first element of an array, but it's still just a pointer. People often think of pointers as being something like arrays, and there is a lot of overlap, but I find it clearer to keep them completely separate.